# Why won't my canvas draw?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

My canvas element isnt working right. It wont draw a rectangle. Please help me diagnose the problem. I don't know where the problem is, is it my css, javascript, or html? Did I set up everything right because I got no errors when i ran my debugger and put it on a server?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Paco Developement</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="game.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvasBg" height="500" width="800"></canvas>
<canvas id="character" height="500" width="800"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
* {
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
}

header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, figure, hgroup{
    display:block;
}

body {
background:#BADA55;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#canvasBg {
display:block;
background:#fff;
margin:100px auto 0px;
}

#character {
display:block;
margin:-500px auto 0px;
}
```

game.js

```
var canvasBg = document.getElementById('canvasBg');
var bgCtx = canvasBg.getContext("2d");

document.addEventListener('load',drawRect,false);

function drawRect(){
bgCtx.fillStyle="#FF0000";
bgCtx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
}
```

Comment: addEventListener should be called on window not document..

Comment: also, try moving your two first statements inside the drawRect function so you're sure they're ready before trying to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8HgVU/)**

Change `document` to `window` for your event listener and it should work for you.

```
window.addEventListener('load',drawRect,false);
```

Comment: exactly my problem also i needed to add the vars in my function